# Use an NPM module directly in the browser

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, browserify

This might be a stupid question, or the answer is so obvious that I just couldn't find it.

Basically I want to use `Redux` in my very simple web app. I wanna be able to include redux like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/redux.js"></script>
```

And just use it directly in my code like this :

```
var store = redux.createStore(...);
```

I tried webpack and browserify but I couldn't make it work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import Redux via a `<script>` tag you have to use the UMD builds.

According to the [docs](https://redux.js.org/#installation), they are present on the [`dist/` folder](https://unpkg.com/redux@3.7.2/dist/).

Answer (score 1):

I got Redux working with their pre-built UMD files.
But to use other NPM modules directly in the browser here's what to to (I don't know if this is the correct method but it worked for me) :

1- Create a simple file `main.js` with :

```
window.Redux = require('redux');
```

2- Install browserify globally :

```
npm install -g browserify
```

3- Browserify the file from the command line (no config files) :

```
browserify main.js -o redux.js
```

Now just include `redux.js` as a `<script>` tag

Comment: missing step: install redux locally >npm i redux --save

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the package directly on the browser for a smaller use case you could use unpkg.com which is a fast prepackage list of everything available on NPM (per the claim on their website)